# How to spy on refs in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have a component that has a `MapView` from `react-native-maps`. I want to test that I'm calling `MapView.fitToSuppliedMarkers()` inside `componentDidUpdate` of my component.

I'm using `enzyme` and `jest` for testing.

My code under test:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    //some other code
    this.refs.map.fitToSuppliedMarkers(/* some parameters */);
}
```

But I struggle on how to access and spy on `this.refs` using `enzyme` and `jest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I relied on deprecated string refs which didn't allow for testing. Once, I upgraded to [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) I was able to spy on refs using the prototype object.

**code under test**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    //some other code
    this.map.fitToSuppliedMarkers(/* some parameters */);
}

render() {
  return (
    <MapView
      ref={(map) => { this.map = map; }}
    >
    </MapView>
  );
}
```

**the unit test**

```
it('zooms in on markers when receiving new data', () => {
  Map.prototype.map = {
    fitToSuppliedMarkers: function () { }
  };

  const spy = spyOn(Map.prototype.map, 'fitToSuppliedMarkers');

  const testee = shallow(
    <Map markers={[]} />
  );

  const withAnimation = true;

  testee.setProps({ markers: markers });

  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(markers, withAnimation);
});
```